# vba Copy text after found text

Tags: vba, excel

Help me to add loop to below code. As of now code copies only first match from text in cell -"26002354". I want it to copy all matches from one cell and than it goes to next cell down.

Lets say - in text i have tree matches(all text in one cell):
26002354
26008541
26009841

All of them i need to get in a row on the right.

```
Sub extract()
    Dim r As Long, dashpos As Long, m As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    m = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 2 To m
        dashpos = InStr(1, Cells(r, 1), "2600")
        Cells(r, 2).Value = Mid(Cells(r, 1), dashpos, 14)
        Cells(r, 3).Value = Mid(Cells(r, 1), dashpos, 14)
        Cells(r, 4).Value = Mid(Cells(r, 1), dashpos, 14)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand... If you want the entire Text, why are you using `Mid` then? Or am I just getting it wrong ..? Just post a mockup of your expected result please... Would be much less confusing

Comment: Split the cell value on the space to get three parts (and qualify the parent of Cells).

Comment: Since you are splitting into the next three columns you could also use TextToColumns.

Comment: Sorry for confusing. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gATAu.jpg Here is example of expected result. I want to extract among text only those words and numbers, that begins from "2600"(whole bumber looks like 26003400699010) and copy it on the right row.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGFur.jpg Correct picture

Answer (score 0):

Your intended result is a little unclear but to get three 8 digit numbers in columns B:D from columns A containing '26002354 26008541 26009841', use Split.

```
Sub extract()
    Dim r As Long

    with Worksheets("Sheet1")
       For r = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
           .Cells(r, 2).resize(1, 3) = split(Cells(r, 1).value2, chr(32))
       Next
    end with
End Sub
```